# Navigation menu not visible (contrast issue) on home page

Tags: menus, css

I am very new on WordPress so my mistake should not be be too complicated.   I did something to my site that the navigation menu items on home (landing) page hidden in the navigation menu [here](http://fullcircletherapy.com/home).

If you hover over where menu items should be they individually appear.  The nav menu items display fine on all subordinate pages.

Ideally, I would like to fix it so that that nav menu items on the home page, are the same as all other pages

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the element, you'll see that header has a different background color than other pages which is transparent. Your nav elements color is also white and that is why you can't see the menus on home page but actually the menu is there. Just change the header background color to #000 as you used for other page header. So you can add following css to your style:

```
#masthead .site-header{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Once you update the css the header will look like normal something like [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/UX9jsCo)

Answer (score 0):

Two Solutions:

Add class `header-bg` to `<body>` tag on home page

**OR**

Add CSS rule `background-color: #000;` to selector `.site-header.fixed` at line No. 900 in `style.css`

```
.site-header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000; /* Add this new rule */
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any solution?